# Jquery fadein adds a flicker before the transition kicks in

Tags: jquery

Hey there :) I'm trying make a fadein transition effect between every page on my website and also a fadeout when you click a link that redirects to the given url. But I get some weird flicker effect before the fadein effect kicks in. Any idea how to solve this problem?

I'm using a no conflict wrapper because i use Wordpress.

```
// Adding Wordpress Jquery selector($) support
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Toggle hamburger menu for mobile devices
    $(".menu-toggle").click(function(){
        $(".main-navigation").toggleClass("navigation-toggle");

    });
    // Transition between pages
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // to fade in on page load
        $("body").css("display", "none");
        $("body").fadeIn(1500); 
     })

    // delegate all clicks on "a" tag (links)
    $(document).on("click", "a", function () {

        // get the href attribute
        var newUrl = $(this).attr("href");

        // veryfy if the new url exists or is a hash
        if (!newUrl || newUrl[0] === "#") {
            // set that hash
            location.hash = newUrl;
            return;
        }

        // now, fadeout the html (whole page)
        $("html").fadeOut(function () {
            // when the animation is complete, set the new location
            location = newUrl;
        });

        // prevent the default browser behavior.
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Try removing `$("body").css("display", "none");`

Answer (score 1):

Try substituting `$("body").css("opacity", "0");` for `$("body").css("display", "none");` , chaining `.fadeTo(1500, 1);` for `$("body").fadeIn(1500);`

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
     // to fade in on page load
     $("body").css("opacity", "0")
     .fadeTo(1500, 1);
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  abc
</body>
```

Comment: The flicker effect happens when i go to another page. There is no flicker effect on index page. put from index -> contact the fadein on body flickers then fades in.

Comment: @MikkelMadsen Tried including same `js` at each page ?

Comment: yea the code is in the wordpress header after jquery lib :/

Comment: @MikkelMadsen Tried removing `$("html").fadeOut()` ? , adding `event` parameter to `click` event, setting `event.preventDefault()` at beginning of `click` handler ?

Comment: That solves the flicker problem on fadein. But then I dont have the fadeout effect, when a user goes from a page to another. 

Is there a better solution to make this effect? Got the idea from a site called "basicagency.com".

Comment: Try adding `jQuery.holdReady(true); $("body").css("opacity", 0); jQuery.holdReady(false)` before first `.ready()` , substituting `$("body").fadeTo(1500, 1, function() {// do location stuff})` for `$("html").fadeOut()`

Comment: how would you write this? Sorry, still a beginner in JS and jQuery :S

Comment: The flicker actually only appears in Google Chrome.

Comment: @MikkelMadsen Tried jsfiddle ?

Comment: Yea can't seem to execute a fadein effect in the function and go the link clicked

Comment: trying to add the location = newUrl; in the function, but can't figure it out hehe.

Comment: im trying this: 

jQuery.holdReady(true);
jQuery("body").css("opacity", 0);
jQuery.holdReady(false);
jQuery(function($) {
  $("body").fadeTo(1500, 1);
    $(document).on("click", "a", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // get the href attribute
  var newUrl = $(this).attr("href");
        $("body").fadeTo(1500, 0, function() {
        // do stuff
        // veryfy if the new url exists or is a hash
            location = newUrl;

     })
    })
})

Comment: jsfiddle results appear block setting `window.location` , try http://jsfiddle.net/gct7h16h/2/

Answer (score 0):

You are fading  body in and html out, Try $('html, body').fadeIn/Out